# SQL Server 2017 OFFSET + FETCH - How to know last result was reached

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table with thousands of entries. I'm building a web application (Razor C#) to present a table with the information.

I have a working pagination system,  However I can't find a way to know if the current result set has the last result.

I've thought of doing:

- pageNumber * resultPerPage < count(all)
- pre-doing the next page and see if it has any results

I need to do this in order to hide the "next" button.
This is my current code (I'm appending this to the query which is built according to the filters set):

```
ORDER BY ID 
OFFSET ((" + page + " - 1) * " + rowsPerPage + ") ROWS
FETCH NEXT " + rowsPerPage + " ROWS ONLY
```

Thank you!

Comment: [No Offset](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset)

Comment: Order by descending.   Then last entry is the first row.

Comment: @lad2025 I'm aware of that, but the limitation of that prevent me from doing accessing direct pages. Plus I also need to go back and forth.

Comment: @jdweng That's a cool idea, however imagine this: I get 50 values on the last page (i'm allowing 100). Then I'm going to get the last value. turns out it gets a new entry (that had just been inserted). I allow the user to use the next page button. But since there was just 50 items on the last result set, the "next page" would appear empty.


If I checked the last entry before returning the result I would have to check every item return to see if it matches the last one. And still if there would be a new entry that needed to go on a new page, the user wouldn't be allow to click "next page"

Comment: Get Count of rows.  If you get 930 rows then last page is to 30 if you have 100 rows per page.  Use Mod function 930 % 100 = 30.  then use TOP(30) function.

Comment: @jdweng Not sure if I'm missing some thing there, but how would I know it's time to do TOP(x) if I don't know I'm in the last page?

Comment: Usually you know total count of rows (for example to display total number of pages). But if you do not for some reason - just query page size + 1 rows and discard last one (if its not there - this page is last)

Comment: If you are using a Synchronous method it blocks until the query completes.

Answer (score 1):

Skip the `OFFSET` clause. Keep track of last ID from previous `SELECT`.

```
WHERE ID > last_id_from_previous_select
ORDER BY ID
FETCH NEXT " + rowsPerPage + " ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

Fetch one more row in your request, namely rowsPerPage+1.
If the returned result set contains rowsPerPage+1 rows, you'll know there's more records to fetch. If it returns less or equal than rowsPerPage rows, there will be no more pages, so you can hide the next button. 
The only cost of this approach is that you get one more records each time.

Comment: In order to hide that "bonus" record I would have to keep count of how many I've shown and that's a "if" per each row... Which is not ideal. Unless there's another way I'm not seeing to remove that bonus one

Comment: it depends on what you do with your records. Just strip an extra records before handling it futher. Suppose, you have a code like this ` var records = getPage(page, rowsPerPage); /* let it be an array of records */ var isLastPage = records.Count()>rowsPerPage; var recordsToDisplay = isLastPage?records: records.Take(rowsPerPage);

Comment: @BrunoTeixeira An if per row?

Comment: What do you mean by per row. I'm afraid I don't understand what you need.